# How to compute the position of an object after free falling for 10 seconds

Tags: java

I'm given this basic code:

```
public class GravityCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double gravity = -9.81; //Earth's gravity in m/s^2
        double initialVelocity = 0.0;
        double fallingTime = 10.0;
        double initialPosition = 0.0;
        double finalPosition = 0.0;
        System.out.println("The object's position after " + fallingTime + " seconds is " + finalPosition+ "m");
        // the output is The object's position after 10.0 seconds is 0.0m
    }
}
```

And I'm told to modify the program to compute the position of an object falling for 10 seconds, using this formula:

```
x(t) = 0.5 * at^2 + v(t) + x
a = acceleration = -9.81 m/s
t = time (in seconds) = 10
v = initial velocity
x = initial position
```

I've tried and tried but the answer I get is `4811.805000000001`,
but apparently the correct answer is `-490.5m`.

This is my attempt:

```
public class GravityCalculator2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double gravity = -9.81;
        double fallingTime = 10;
        double initialVelocity = 0.0;
        double initialPosition = 0.0;
        double x;
        x = (0.5 * ((gravity * fallingTime) * (gravity * fallingTime)) 
            + (initialVelocity * fallingTime) + (initialPosition));
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you post your calculation code so we can see where you are going wrong?

Comment: You squared the gravitational constant, that's what you did wrong.

Answer (score 25):

You're code is evaluating this equation:

> x(t) = 0.5 * **(at)<sup>2</sup>** + v(t) + x

when it should be evaluating:

> x(t) = 0.5 * **a(t<sup>2</sup>)** + v(t) + x

The normal understanding of math notation is that exponentiation binds tighter than multiplication.

Answer (score 7):

You coded up the formula wrong:

```
x(t) = 0.5 * at^2 + v(t) + x
```

is what you started with but you coded up:

```
x(t) = 0.5 * (at)^2 + v(t) + x
```

Order of operations is important!

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting 4811 is because you are squaring both the acceleration due to gravity and the time in your first term. You are only supposed to be squaring the time and then multiplying that by the acceleration due to gravity and 0.5. Remember your order of operations. Also, acceleration due to gravity is negative, so you should have -9.81 instead of 9.81.